# Remove styling from input

Tags: php

I have a WYSIWG that I know people will copy and paste into. When I they do on there server side I want to strip everything in between the tags so its juts `<p></p>` or `<span></span>`.

My test Copy/Paste looks like:

```
<p style="color: rgb(26, 26, 26); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;">"<span style="font-weight: 700;">Nancy</span>"</p><p style="color: rgb(26, 26, 26); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;">5 rounds for time of:<br>400 meter run<br>95 pound Overhead squat, 15 reps</p>
```

I saw this:

```
preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $input )
```

but it returns:

```
<pOpen Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;">"<span>Nancy</span>"</p><pOpen Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;">5 rounds for time of:<br>400 meter run<br>95 pound Overhead squat, 15 reps</p>
```

So it stripped the `Style:` part but left the actual styles.

Comment: I've updated my anwser. I've misunderstanding your question. Does it works now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this following regular expression that keep only the tags:

```
$input = preg_replace('~(<[a-z]+)[^>]+~', '$1', $input );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the complete style tag, this should work for you:

```
preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $input);
```

However if you want to save these files somewhere into a database, you might want to do some more checking for the code.

As well you can (in most WYSIWYG Editors) select whicht functions users can use. So if you only want to allow specific html tags and attributes, you should be able to set this.

This does NOT replace code checking before inserting into a db, since you can of course turn off java and insert what you want.

Comment: I tried `preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1',`  (its in the original question) but it doesnt work properly with an actual copy/paste a user did

Comment: It´s actually not the same code :). Its verified working for inline style tags ;)